# Problem about sprite rotation and collision in GameMaker Studio 2

Tags: game-maker-studio-2, game-maker-language

After rotating the texture with image_angle, I encounter a problem with the place_meeting function.

I originally intended for my character (the red ball in the image) to lose health when it touches the bullet (the black line in the image), but it ends up losing health whenever the character is within the dashed line area.

[image]

I tried to replace `draw_self` to `draw_sprite_ext` but it makes no difference. I've searched on Google about it many times, but it all still didn't work.

Comment: Have you checked your collision mask? I think you should use a circular-shaped collision mask instead.